# Error : Unable to retrieve API Documentation

Tags: symfony, react-admin, api-platform.com

I am a beginner I have to solve a problem on an application in progress. The back office was working but today it does not work anymore. I have control over the doc Api platform admin, everything seems ok. when i start the admin mode in localhost an error is displayed: Unable to retrieve API Documentation.
Can you help me ?
Thank you

**App.js**

```jsx
 import React from 'react';
 import { HydraAdmin } from '@api-platform/admin';
 require('dotenv').config();

 export default () => <HydraAdmin entrypoint= {process.env.REACT_APP_API} />;`
```

**nelmio_cors.yaml**

```yaml
nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        origin_regex: true
        allow_origin: ['*']
        allow_methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']
        allow_headers: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization']
        expose_headers: ['Content-Disposition', 'Content-Length', 'Link']
        max_age: 3600
    paths:
        '^/': ~`
```

**.env**

```
######API ENV#######
REACT_APP_API=http://localhost:8080/
```

Comment: Can you check the log for giving us more info please?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

In dev.log : 

[2019-04-18 10:43:20] request.INFO: Matched route "swagger_ui". {"route":"swagger_ui","route_parameters":{"_route":"swagger_ui","_controller":"api_platform.swagger.action.ui"},"request_uri":"http://localhost:8080/doc","method":"GET"} []

Comment: and [2019-04-18 10:43:20] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []